# How to add a button programmatically to a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How can i use the linearLayout and the params variables from protected void onCreate, in the second protected void finishButton? I need to add finishButton to the linearLayout. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int score = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(0, 110, 0, 0);
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

        TextView iq_Test_Title = new TextView(this);
        iq_Test_Title.setText("Text");
        iq_Test_Title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        iq_Test_Title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        iq_Test_Title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        linearLayout.addView(iq_Test_Title);

        finishButton();

        // other code
    }

    protected void finishButton() {
        final Button finishButton = new Button(this);
        finishButton.setText(R.string.finish_button);
        finishButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(finishButton);

        finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finishButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: first add text to your layout after that add your layout to scrollview. might that would be helpful. and also keep in mind that scrollview can't contain more than one child.

Comment: Treat LinearLayout as Viewgroup **"Viewgroup group = (ViewGroup)linearLayout;"** and then try to add button as view.

Comment: The problem si not that i can't add the button, i can't see the linearLayout  in the second private void, to add it, because the linearLayout  it's declared in the first. How can i use the linearLayout in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the view inside the `finishButton` method, just make it a class level variable:

```
public class MyActivity...
   private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

   protected void onCreate(..){
      mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
      ...
   }

   private void finishButton(){
      ...
      mLinearLayout.addView(..);
   }
}
```

Comment: I used `linearLayout.addView(iq_Test_Title);` but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh I see that now. Is the linearlayout getting added to the scrollview? Also why bother to do these programatically and not in the XML?

Comment: I am going to edit my answer. The problem is that the linearlayout is only in scope of the onCreate method, you need to give it the scope of that class if you want to use it in multiple methods.

Comment: And how can i give the scope of that class? Because i want to use it in multiple methods.

Comment: See my edited answer. Declare an object at the class level, and assign it a value inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: I did exactly how you said. The `linearLayout ` variable is no more underlined with red in Android Studio (in the second private void), but still not working. It says: Private field `linearLayout ` is never assigned.

Comment: That's likely because you didn't change the code in `onCreate()` to be referencing that same linearlayout. Inside that method change `final LinearLayout linearLayout` to just `linearLayout` so they reference the same object.

Comment: Fair enough, it's no more underlined in red but when i, run my emulator i get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference`.
Don't know what to do.

Comment: You're calling `linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this)` before you're adding a view to it, right?

Comment: Hmm well I'm not sure why the linearLayout is considered null. :/

Comment: I rewritte the code again, with your specification, and now it-s working.

Comment: @AlexM. glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. This can aid future readers who stumble upon this question.

Comment: I already did. Simple `linearLayout` was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want to return the button to the caller from finishButton().  Then add it to the view in onCreate.

Change your declaration of finishButton to

```
protected Button finishButton()
```

After you've got it configured, add the line:

```
return finishButton;
```

at the end of that method.  Then in onCreate:

```
linearLayout.addView(finishButton());
```